# Sum of two or more column using openpyxl python

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I want Sum of two or more column for more then 100 rows in a sheet using openpyxl python module.
Below is the code sample

```
for m in range(0,100):
  sheet.cell(row=m+1,column=5).value=(sheet.cell(row=m+1,column=3).value) + (sheet.cell(row=m+1,column=4))
```

But not working.
Please suggest any other method using openpyxl only as my other loop and code-part using openpyxl function.

Comment: Not a [mre] - not clear what your problem is (beside "not working"). What happens, what is wanted, whats wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to get the `value` property for column 4.

This should fix your problem:

```py
for m in range(0, 100):
    col3_value = sheet.cell(row=m + 1, column=3).value
    col4_value = sheet.cell(row=m + 1, column=4).value
    sheet.cell(row=m + 1, column=5).value = col3_value + col4_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use a function like this:

```
import openpyxl


def val(x, y):
    return sheet_obj.cell(row=x, column=y).value


path = "test.xlsx"
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

for m in range(1, 11):
    sheet_obj.cell(row=m, column=3).value = val(m, 1) + val(m, 2)
wb_obj.save(path)
```

test.xlsx file :

[image]

output:

[image]

Comment: No, it is not really better because you add one level of complexity for no real improvement.